# Why bash is closed while writing to named pipe?

Tags: bash, named-pipes

**In bash 1:**

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/pipe
$ echo 'something' > /tmp/pipe
```

Now it hangs and waits that data to be read.

**In bash 2:**

```
$ </tmp/pipe
```

Now shell 1 goes away, it is closed, my terminal is gone.

**Why is this happening?**

In bash manual there is written

> The command  substitution  $(cat file) can be replaced by the
>   equivalent but faster $(< file).

So I was experimenting if plain "< file" works in a similar way to cat file content to terminal.

```
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-71-generic (buildd@lgw01-46) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #92~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 23:31:46 UTC 2016
```

**Edit**

After seeing initial comments and answers I will add a bit of clarification.

I'm not concerned about different command line syntaxes.

But what I was really after was that in reader shell `$ < /tmp/pipe` scenario writer shell exits, but with `$ cat /tmp/pipe` in reader shell the writer shell does not exit. Why?

I see that I really did not phrase that in question and in body and should probably initiate another question?

Comment: `$(< file)` is a special case for command substitutions; `< file` is not a universal replacement for `cat file`.

Answer (score 1):

From [the `pipe(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html):

> If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a `write(2)` will cause a `SIGPIPE` signal to be generated for the calling process.

What happens is that when the reading shell has finished reading and closes its end of the pipe, the writing shell will receive the `SIGPIPE` signal, and if it doesn't catch it then the shell will be terminated.

Comment: I don't think they are asking that. I think they are asking why it doesn't output anything if the use `<` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @123 The question title "Why bash is closed while writing to named pipe?" indicates otherwise.

Comment: In that case it is an obvious duplicate and should be marked as one.

Comment: This is correct. You can see it if you do `(echo something > /tmp/pipe); echo $?`. This will print `141`, which is `128+13`, and `13` is `SIGPIPE`. So the subshell was killed with SIGPIPE.

Comment: Why "cat /tmp/pipe" does not cause SIGPIPE to writer while "</tmp/pipe" does?

Answer (score 0):

In manual sign `$` is connected with `variable` not `command prompt`.

Try the following scripts:

1)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(< /tmp/pipe);
```

2)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(cat /tmp/pipe);
```

Both works correctly.

Comment: He's not typing `$`, he's just showing that as the command prompt.

Comment: Yes. I means `$` in `$(< file)`, not in `$ </tmp/pipe`

Comment: What does this have to do with the question, which is why the process that does `echo something > /tmp/pipe` goes away?

Comment: I don't know what does it mean command `< /tmp/pipe`, but explain that in documentation there is example of using `$(< /tmp/pipe)`. 

Summarizing:

      cat /tmp/pipe - print `something` on screen,
      $(cat /tom/pipe) - execute `something` as command,
      $(< /tmp/pipe) - execute `something` faster.

In my opinion `< /tmp/pipe` is incorrect command.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `< /tmp/pipe`, you connect the standard input of the current shell to the named pipe instead. `bash` works by continuously reading from its input and executing what it reads as a command.

1. In shell 1, `echo something > /tmp/pipe` opens the pipe for writing, writes the string, then blocks until something reads it. As soon as `echo` completes, it will close its end of the pipe.
2. `< /tmp/pipe` opens the pipe for reading, and connects it to shell 2's standard input.
3. Shell 2 reads from the pipe (and tries to execute a command).
4. Back in shell 1, the `echo`, having unblocked after the 2nd shell read from the pipe, completes. The write end of the pipe closes.
5. With the write-end of the pipe closed, shell 2 will get a `SIGPIPE` when it tries to read another command, then exit.

(An alternate possibility is that shell 2 exits if the command it reads from the pipe and tries to execute causes an error.)

`$(< file)`, on the other hand, is a special case of command substitution. When `bash` sees that, it simply reads from `file` itself, rather than spawning a `cat` process and capturing its output.

Comment: Writer shell (1) gets SIGPIPE on finishing write(). Reader shell (2) does not exit.